# ASPX Password textbox

Tags: asp.net, .net, textbox, passwords

By default, the password fieldbox masked all the text the user typed as ******.

I want to be able to display a string on the Password field box.

So it should says "Please enter your Password" initially when the password control is loaded.

Currently aspx showing it as ***************

How can i best achieve this?

Cheers

Comment: Add textbox markup/html to your question.

Comment: [check this out](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2012/05/aspnet-set-watermark-text-for-password.html)

Answer (score 1):

Use TextMode.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="Password" runat="server" TextMode="Please enter your Password"  
onclick="this.value=''; this.type='password'; ">Password                                                    
</asp:TextBox>
```

or

Use placeholder.

For EX:

```
<input type="password" placeholder="Please enter your Password">
```

Comment: This is not a password textbox. I want to be able to show the password masked when the user type

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it using jquery:

**HTML:**

```
<input id="password" value="password" class="password-input" />
```

**JS:**

```
$('.password-input').bind('click', function() {
    if ($(this).val() === "Please enter your Password")
    {
       this.type = "password";
       $(this).val(''); 
    }
});

$('.password-input').bind('blur', function() {
    if ($(this).val() === "")
    {
       this.type = "text";
       $(this).val('Please enter your Password');
    }
});
```

**JSFIDDLE:**

**http://jsfiddle.net/V2Dh5/3/**

*You can also see previous SO questions about the same thing:*

**[Set default value of a password input so it can be read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797166/set-default-value-of-a-password-input-so-it-can-be-read)**

**[Set Default Value Of A Password Input / A Scenario / Issue in IE 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7938885/set-default-value-of-a-password-input-a-scenario-issue-in-ie-8)**

**[default value for asp.net textbox -> TextMode = password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7977305/default-value-for-asp-net-textbox-textmode-password)**